# Are there existing examples of this type of game

Tags: game-theory

I'm new to the topic and have begun reading some of the literature out there. I have been trying to find examples of a type of game to see if it already exists but did not have much luck.

Are there examples of two player cooperative games where Player A can communicate with Player B but Player B cannot communicate with Player A and the goal is to maximize their cumulative rewards. Think Player A gets a reward if they communicate helpful information to Player B and Player B gets a reward if they were able to use the information that Player A gave.

This is the general framework of the game and I've tried to keep it as general as possible to hopefully see if there are multiple examples out there that look at this.

Any insights would be appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: I‘m sorry but this is the wrong stackexchange. Game theory is a mathematical field and not a game critique tag. Maybe https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ would be right for this kind of question?

Comment: Not related to maths at all, but "Keep talking and nobody explodes" is a game like that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was asking this question here in the hopes that someone knows of existing game theory literature that describes games that resemble the one that I described. Of course the framework can be more specific but I kept it general to hopefully get many examples of this. I can delete the question if it is deemed too irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe you can formulate your problem as a Stackelberg game, http://web.stanford.edu/~rjohari/teaching/notes/246_lecture7_2007.pdf

Comment: As an aside, this almost certainly wouldn't fall under combinatorial game theory as those games do not have hidden information that A could communicate about.

Comment: An idea: think about prisoner's dilemma where person A can tell person B that he will not cooperate.

Comment: Maybe you could work with two filtrations and formulate some kind of optimal stopping problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be looking for is called a signaling game or the related screening game. Signaling games are two-stage games where player 1, has some private information and moves first. The move of Player 1 is observed by Player 2. Player 2 moves second, possibly getting a "signal" from observing the move of player 1. In a screening game it is reversed player 2, the uniformed actor, moves first.